# Update a collection in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We have a syntax of 'USING timestamp' to provide client timestamps to cassandra. Is it possible to provide client timestamp to each value of the collection map or collection list ?

Thanks
Sreeni

Answer (score 2):

For map:

```
UPDATE table USING TIMESTAMP xxx SET map[key]=value WHERE partition=yyy
```

For list:

```
//Append
UPDATE table USING TIMESTAMP xxx SET list=list + value WHERE partition=yyy

//Prepend
UPDATE table USING TIMESTAMP xxx SET list=value + list WHERE partition=yyy
```

I personally would **not** recommend playing with list timestamp considering how Cassandra handle list cells internally. Playing with map element timestamp is ok.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out and get back to you